# Python json pulling list of items

Tags: python, api, loops, request

I apologize in advance if this is simple. This is my first go at Python and I've been searching and trying things all day and just haven't been able to figure out how to accomplish what I need.

I am pulling a list of assets from an API. Below is an example of the result of this request (in reality it will return 50 sensorpoints.
There is a second request that will pull readings from a specific sensor based on sensorPointId. I need to be able to enter an assetId, and pull the readings from each sensor.

```
{
  "assetId": 1436,
  "assetName": "Pharmacy",
  "groupId": "104",
  "groupName": "West",
  "environment": "Freezer",
  "lastActivityDate": "2021-01-25T18:54:34.5970000Z",
  "tags": [
    "Manager: Casey",
    "State: Oregon"
  ],
  "sensorPoints": [
    {
      "sensorPointId": 126,
      "sensorPointName": "Top Temperature",
      "devices": [
        "23004000080793070793",
        "74012807612084533500"
      ]
    },
    {
      "sensorPointId": 129,
      "sensorPointName": "Bottom Temperature",
      "devices": [
        "86004000080793070956"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

My plan was to go through the list from the first request, make a list of all the sensorpointIds in that asset then run the second request for each based on that list.  The problem no matter which method I try to pull the individual sensorpointIds, it says object is not subscriptable, even when looking at a string value. These are all the things I've tried. I'm sure it's something silly I'm missing, but all of these I have seen in examples. I've written the full response to a text file just to make sure I'm getting good data, and that works fine.

```
r = request...
data = r.json
for sensor in data:
print (data["sensorpointId")

or 
print(["sensorsPoints"]["sensorPointName"])

these give 'method' object is not iterable

I've also just tried to print a single sensorpointId
print(data["sensorpointId"][0]) 
print(data["sensorpointName"][0])
print(data["sensorPoints"][0]["sensorpointId"])

all of these give object is not subscriptable

print(r["sensorPoints"][0]["sensorpointName"])
'Response' object is not subscriptable
print(data["sensorPoints"][0]["sensorpointName"])

print(["sensorPoints"][0]["sensorpointName"]
string indices must be integers, not 'str'
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post and format the code blocks (including commenting and proper indentation) (see [How do I format my code blocks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)).

Answer (score 0):

I got it!

```
data = r.json()['sensorPoints']
sensors = []
for d in data:
sensor = d['sensorPointId']
sensors.append(sensor)
```